# 'Email is badly formatted' react-native firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

This is how i called firebase auth:

```
onButtonPress() {
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    console.log(email,password);
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err);
              firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                 .catch( (err) => {
                     console.log(err);
                    this.setState({ error: err.message });
             });
        });
   }
```

Here is my auth textInput:

```
<Card>
        <CardSection>
            <Input
                secureTextEntry={false}
                label={'E-mail'}
                placeholder={'user@gmail.com'}
                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                value={this.state.email}
            />
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
            <Input
                secureTextEntry={true}
                label={'Password'}
                placeholder={'password'}
                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                value={this.state.password}

            />
        </CardSection>
        <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>{this.state.error}</Text>
        <CardSection>
            <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                Log In
            </Button>
       </CardSection>
</Card>
```

But when it runs its showing me message like :

[image]

this error pops even if i don't input any email and password in input and press submit.

Comment: Can we see the onButtonPress method ? and what is the problem ? yes empty is not a well formatted email

Comment: @cladClad i have updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is happening due to a default space the **this.state.email** caused. using **trim()** and sending it to server stopped the error from happening. This is working piece of code.

```
const {email, password} = this.state;
    this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
        .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
        .catch( (err) => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password)
                .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
                .catch(this.onLoginFailed.bind(this));
        });
```

Comment: it says email.trim() the function .trim() is not defined !

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, your create user function is in login catch block. Seperate them and Just simply do this when you create user: I mean for register.

`firebaseRef.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((userData) => {//userData}).catch((error) => {//error});`

for login:

`firebaseRef.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((userData) => {//userData}).catch((error) => {//error});`

and also you have been logged in when you signed up

note: firebaseRef is reference of Firebase.initializeApp(config);

Comment: i tried with your code, got the same error.. 

 code: "auth/invalid-email", message: "The email address is badly formatted."

Comment: Was the sign up process successful? Are you sending email correctly to services ? if you did everything correctly i'm not sure why is happening.

Comment: yes, i have found that this.state.email has extra space in it. trim() saved me from that problem.  

Now getting one new issue. 

A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Comment: when first time i used firebase, i realized react native debugger cause problem like "A network error " for firebase , i dont remember why or how did i manage to solve this problem. Close debugger and try again to see if its debugger.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase  it's a small JS bridge to native side, i think it will solve your problem for debugger.